# R package for hexagonal lattice tesselation of continental US

Tags: r, geospatial, geography, hexagonal-tiles, tessellation

Does anyone know of an R package that will generate an optimal hexagonal cell lattice to tessellate the continental US?  The package should allow the user-specification of a cell-size and it should return the area of the US that is covered by the resultant lattice.